# how to use Multibinding.StringFormat on Fill property of a rectangle?

Tags: xaml, multibinding

I've created an ItemControl with a dataTemplate that contains a rectangle that will be colorized based of the ItemsSource. The date being fed to my application is a color hex code that does not contain the hash sign (#). Just a 6-character string. To get the color to show up correctly i need to format the 6-character string with the # in front of it. exp #A31F34

Here's the XAML

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColorSequenceSwatchPreviews">
    <Rectangle Name="ColorSwatch" Height="20" Width="120" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,3">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Fill">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.StringFormat><![CDATA[#{0}]]></MultiBinding.StringFormat>
                            <Binding Path="InnerXml" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

I'm using a MultiBinding.StringFormat to format the string into a Hexcode properly, but am stumped as to why the fill of the rectangle is not colorizing.

I am able to get the rectangle to colorize if I do the MultiBinding with a TextBox, then bind the rectangle's fill property to the Text property of the textBox. However, I would much prefer binding directly from the rectangle's fill property like in my first example since it is cleaner.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColorSequenceSwatchPreviews">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox x:Name="Hexcode" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding>
                <MultiBinding.StringFormat><![CDATA[#{0}]]></MultiBinding.StringFormat>
                <Binding Path="InnerXml" Mode="OneWay" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <Rectangle Name="ColorSwatch"  Height="20" Width="120" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ElementName=Hexcode,Path=,Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to get the first example to work or am i stuck with using the code from the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved far more easily using a Converter. You don't even need `MultiBinding` for it. Simple `Binding` with a `Converter` should do it:

Here is the converter:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(String), GetType(SolidColorBrush))>
Public Class HexToBrushConverter
  Implements IValueConverter

  Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Return DirectCast(New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#" & value.ToString()), SolidColorBrush)
  End Function

  Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return Nothing
  End Function
End Class
```

All you need to do now is to create an object of the converter in your Resources section:

```
<local:HexToBrushConverter x:Key="HexToBrushConverter" />
```

(local is the namespace of your project where you define this converter class)

and then use it in the `Fill` property:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=Hexcode, Path=, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HexToBrushConverter}}" />
```

Comment: was hoping for something that didn't involve any code behind. I do like this solution though!